# How to prove Gauss’s Multiplication Formula?

Tags: gamma-function

How to prove Gauss’s Multiplication Formula?

$$\Gamma(nz)=(2\pi)^{(1-n)/2}n^{nz-(1/2)}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(z+\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GtMQ.png))

Any help like an answer or link would be appreciated. Thanks for all help.

Comment: See [Clasical Analysis by E. Chiang](http://www.math.ust.hk/~machiang/391N/Classical_Analysis.pdf). The statement of Gauss's Multiplication Theorem is on page 45 and the proof begins on the next.

Comment: @JacobMayle thanks alot

Comment: @JacobMayle Me too, a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof along Ahlfors' lines would be to differentiate both side and use the identity
$$
\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)})=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(z+n)^{2}}
$$
on both sides of the equation. It is easy to verify that $\Gamma(z)$ and $\prod^{n-1}_{i=0}\Gamma(\frac{z}{n}+\frac{i}{n})$ has the same poles, and taking log derivative on both sides give you an extra $n^{2}$ factor. So all we need is to fix the constant and the $e^{az+b}$ term. But at this point I do not know how to derive it rigorously, and I think the textbook others suggested might help.

I found there is a direct proof here:

[Ahlfors "Prove the formula of Gauss"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752895/ahlfors-prove-the-formula-of-gauss)