# Showing $\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}[1+\cosh(x\pi)]^{-n}dx={(2n-2)!!\over (2n-1)!!}\cdot{2\over 2^n}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Showing

> $$\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}[1+\cosh(x\pi)]^{-n}dx={(2n-2)!!\over (2n-1)!!}\cdot{2\over 2^n}\tag1$$

Recall

$$1+\cosh(x\pi)={(e^{x\pi}+1)^2\over 2e^{x\pi}}\tag2$$

$$I_n=2^n\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{xn\pi}\over (1+e^{x\pi})^{2n}}dx\tag3$$

$$I_n={2^n\pi\over n\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}n\pi e^{nx\pi}(1+e^{x\pi})^{-2n}dx\tag4$$

$$I_n=\left.{2^n\over n}\cdot{1\over (1+e^{x\pi})^{2n-1}}\right|_{0}^{\infty}\tag5$$

$$I_n={1\over n(2n-1)2^{n-1}}\tag6$$

Help, where did I went wrong?

---

New Edit

From (3) we make a substitution

let $u=x\pi \rightarrow du=dx$

$$I_n=2^n\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{un}(1+e^u)^{-2n}du\tag{3a}$$

Comment: @AlexR. which is the same :) as the OP stated, it holds $1+\cosh(\pi x) = 1+\frac{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}}{2}={(e^{x\pi}+1)^2\over 2e^{x\pi}}$

Comment: You somehow introduced an $n$ into $(1+e^{n\pi x})^{2n}$. It should be $(1+e^{x\pi})^{2n}$

Comment: The main issue is that $$ n x^{\color{red}{n}}\neq \frac{d}{dx} x^n.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio which happens where exactly (I guess you refer to the substitution but this seems to be fine)

Comment: @user190080: between $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Comment: you might consider to ask a new question on how to go on solving the last integral (could imagine that integration by parts might be helpful) otherwise, the answers below somehow won't fit to your question any longer

Comment: Thank you, I will change it back and make a new edi below it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: remove the useless constant by setting $x=\frac{z}{\pi}$. Then, through $z=\log u$ and $v=\frac{1}{u}$:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+\cosh(z))^{-n}\,dz = 2^n\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(2+u+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-n}}{u}\,du=2^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(2+v+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-n}}{v}\,dv$$
so the LHS equals:
$$ 2^{n-1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^{n-1} du}{(u+1)^{2n}}\,du = 2^n\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{2n-1}\,dt}{(1+t^2)^{2n}}= 2^{n-1} B(n,n) = 2^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n)^2}{\Gamma(2n)}.$$

As an alternative, just apply IBP multiple times.
 It leads to a recursion similar to the one for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}(\theta)\,d\theta.$

Comment: +1, but I think you lack a $dt$ in the second integral of the second row

Comment: @giobrach: thank you, now fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Take $u=\tanh\left(x\right)
 $, then $\cosh\left(x\right)=\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}
 $ and $dx=\frac{2du}{1-u^{2}}
 $ so $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\cosh\left(x\right)+1\right)^{n}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{\left(1-u^{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}+1\right)^{n}}du
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-u^{2}\right)^{n-1}du=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-v\right)^{n-1}v^{-1/2}dv=\frac{B\left(1/2,n\right)}{2^{n}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(n-1\right)!}{\Gamma\left(n+1/2\right)}.$$

Comment: (+1) There is a nice side-effect: our answers together prove the Legendre duplication formula :D

Answer (score 2):

Let $I(n)$ be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\left(1+\cosh(\pi x)\right)^n}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\left(1+\cosh(x)\right)^n}\,dx\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, using the identity $1+\cosh(x)=\frac12 e^{x}\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=2^n\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-nx}}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^{2n}}\,dx\\\\
&=2^n\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{2n}}\,dx\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Now, making the substitution $x\to 1/x$ in $(2)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=2^n\int_1^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{2n}}\,dx \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$I(n)=2^{n-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{2n}}\,dx \tag 4$$

Then, enforcing the substitution $x\to \frac{x}{1-x}$ in $(4)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=2^{n-1}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}\,dx\\\\
&=2^{n-1}B(n,n)\\\\
&=2^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma^2(n)}{\Gamma(2n)}\\\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!}{(2n-1)!!}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)!!}{2^{n-1}(2n-1)!!}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Are you sure, Mark? Numerics don't match. After "*reveals*" we should have $I(n)=2^n\left(\ldots\right)$, for instance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Working on it ... yes there is an error.  Thanks!!

Comment: @chinacat Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark