# Is it possible to prove Gamma function's duplication formula without complex analysis?

Tags: gamma-function

For Gamma function's duplication formula
$$\Gamma (z)\;\Gamma \left(z+{\frac  {1}{2}}\right)=2^{{1-2z}}\;{\sqrt  {\pi }}\;\Gamma (2z)$$
, if limit $z$ to real numbers, i.e. $z\in \mathbb R$, is it possible to prove it using basic analysis, i.e. not relying on complex analysis or beta, zeta etc functions?

Comment: Not within my lifetime.  Especially if you meant the full duplication formula.

Comment: not sure what is "full duplication formula", basically i'd like to find a proof of the formula above, within $\mathbb R$, not using complex analysis. @SimpleArt

Comment: Use the limit definition along with $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt \pi$.

Comment: @Dr.MV The one from Mohr-Bollerup theorem?  Looks promising

Comment: @Dr.MV would u pls elaborate? I only know $\Gamma(s) := \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x} dx$

Comment: @SimpleArt: on the contrary, it is not that difficult. Please see below.

Comment: @athos I have posted an answer that elaborates on my comment.  Furthermore, it embeds a link to another answer I posted in which I showed how to derive the limit formula, $\Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^x\,n!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)}$,from the integral formula, $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}\,e^{-t}\,dt$,directly.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV saw it and printed out. However didn't got time to read as busy fixing a bug now :(

Comment: @athos No worry.  When you have a chance to have a look, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @MarkViola it’s a late reply... finally in a holiday I just went through Emil Artin’s Gamma Function and now I understood your answer! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @athos  You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576), I showed using real analysis only that the Gamma function, $\Gamma(x)$, as defined by the integral, $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}\,e^{-t}\,dt$, $x>0$, can be represented by the limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\Gamma(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^x\,n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n)}} \tag 1$$

Deonte by $G_n(x)$ the sequence of functions

$$G_n(x)=\frac{n^x\,n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n)} \tag2$$

Then, using $(2)$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
G_n(x)G_n(x+1/2)&=\left(\frac{n^x\,n!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)}\right)\left(\frac{2^{n+1}\,n^{x+1/2}\,n!}{(2x+1)(2x+3)\cdots (2x+(2n+1))}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2^{2n+2}n^{2x+1/2}(n!)^2}{(2x)(2x+1)\cdots (2x+2n+1)}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{2^{2n+2}n^{1/2}\color{green}{(n!)^2}}{\color{red}{(2n)!}2^{2x}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2x+2n+1}\right)\color{blue}{\overbrace{\left(\frac{(2n)^{2x}(2n)!}{(2x)(2x+1)\cdots(2x+2n)}\right)}^{G_{2n}(2x)}}\tag 3\\\\
&\sim \left(\frac{2^{2n+2}n^{1/2}\color{green}{(2\pi n)\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}}{\color{red}{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}2^{2x}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2x+2n+1}\right)\color{blue}{G_{2n}(2x)} \tag 4\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2^{2x-1}}\right)\left(\frac{2n}{2x+2n+1}\right)\,G_{2n}(2x)
\end{align}$$

where [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) was used in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$.  Finally, letting $n\to\infty$ and appealing to $(1)$ yields the coveted relationship

$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x+1/2)=2^{1-2x}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let we consider
$$ f(z) = \frac{\Gamma(2z)\,\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(z+1/2)}.$$
Since $\Gamma(z)$ never vanishes, $f(z)$ is a continuous function on its domain. The singularity of the $\Gamma$ function are simple poles at the negative integers: in particular, the structure of the denominator and numerator of $f(z)$ implies that $f$ has no singularity and no zero on the real line. Since $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$, we also have:

$$ \frac{f(z+1)}{f(z)} = \frac{(2z+1)(2z)}{z(z+1/2)} = 4 $$
hence it follows that $f(z)=C\cdot 4^z$. By computing $f(z)$ at $z=1$ we get the explicit value of $C$, hence Legendre's duplication formula through a real-analytic version of Herglotz' trick.

You may perform just the same trick to prove the full multiplication formula in the real case.

An efficient alternative is to consider $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cdot )$ of both terms. Since
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x) = \psi(x) = -\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x-1}\right) $$
the duplication/multiplication formula for the $\Gamma$ function can be derived from the duplication/multiplication formula for the $\psi$ function, that is simple to prove through elementary series manipulations.

As a third alternative, Legendre duplication formula can be proved by computing
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{d\theta}{(1+\cosh\theta)^n} $$
in two different ways, as done by me and Marco Cantarini [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818988/showing-pi-int-0-infty1-coshx-pi-ndx-2n-2-over-2n-1-cdo).