# Prove the following Gauss formula

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I was doing exercises for ahlfors's Complex Analysis book and came across the following problem
$$(2π)^{\frac{n－1}{2}}\Gamma(z)＝n^{z－\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{z}{n})\Gamma(\frac{z＋1}{n})...\Gamma(\frac{z＋n－1}{n})$$
I'm going to move the right side to the left side and use the formula for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$And then I put in  $\frac{z}{n}$, $\frac{z＋1}{n}$and so on,But in the end, I found that the more and more complicated the formula, I realized that maybe my starting point is wrong, but I can't think of a better way to do this problem, so who can give me a little help

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752895/42969

Comment: (Note that you are using non-standard plus and minus characters in the formula, that's why it is displayed so badly.)